# How do I send text to a Redactor WYSIWYG editor box using Watir-WebDriver?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm a new user to Watir and Ruby. I have a watir-webdriver script that fills out forms on a page and submits them. The page has a few [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) WYSIWYG editor boxes and I'm trying to send text to them. Originally I did the following:

```
@browser.div(:id => 'redactor-container-5').send_keys 'automated test script'
```

However, I then found out that Firefox had to be in the foreground for this to work (this is a problem for my team since the scripts they run are sometimes in the background). So instead I used some JavaScript to fill out this same field.

```
@browser.execute_script('var html="automated test script"; $(".redactor, .redactorCaption, .redactorTitle").redactor("insertHtml", html);')
```

However, this too required the browser to be in the foreground (this works completely fine in the foreground). I took a look at [this link](http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/12/automate-entering-text-into-wysiwyg-editors-using-watir-webdriver/) but there was not a Redactor example. Does anyone know how to set these fields when they are in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on my machine, and it works perfectly even when FF is minimized.

```
irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new :ff
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x454b6ab6 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto "http://imperavi.com/redactor/"
=> "http://imperavi.com/redactor/"
irb(main):004:0> b.div(:class => 'redactor_ redactor_editor').send_keys 'automated test script'
=> ""
```

Before executing the last step, i actually minimized Firefox.

Env. details:

Running Windows 7 Enterpricse SP1 (64bit)

Firefox 24.4.0 ESR

watir-webdriver (0.6.9)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response.

I'm wondering if this has anything to do with my operating system. I'm running OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks) and Firefox 28.0. I ran the code above and it works when the window is minimized (or in the foreground) but does not work if the code is in the background.

Comment: I will test on Mac and will let you know if it works.